# Two AsyncTask (second can not be done)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

First AsyncTask is with

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
while(true)
//...getting chat messages from IRC server
}
```

After clicking on button Open Account I starting another AsyncTask with json

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



       JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("https://"),"GET", params);
      //..........
}
```

Second AsyncTask can not be done because first is running and don't let to second get connection.

**How to set on pause the first AsyncTask and resume after done of the second? on pause, because I can't stop first**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start the second AsyncTask using another executor...

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html